# Rate of Reaction - Potassium Permanganate and Hydrogen Peroxide

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetics, rate-equation

I'm interested in an aerospace project that requires I know the reaction rate ($[\pu{M/s}]$) of,
$$\ce{2 KMnO4 (aq) + 3 H2O2 (aq) -> 3 O2 (g) + 2 MnO2 (s) + 2 KOH (aq) + 2H2O (l)}.$$

I'm just curious if there is an analytic method for finding it?

To that end, I also feel I should double-check. To predict the heat ($[\pu{kJ}]$) released I only need to do the following calculation:
$$\Delta H_\mathrm{reaction} = \sum\Delta H_\mathrm{products} - \sum\Delta H_\mathrm{reactants}$$

Is this correct?

My goal is to predict the thrust generated by a hypothetical propulsion system, using this reaction as opposed to combustion.

My thought is if I can derive a theoretical reaction rate then I can calculate a theoretical value for $\mathrm{d}\Delta H_\mathrm{reaction}/\mathrm{d}t$, then thanks to the ideal gas law and thermal physics I should be able to calculate a theoretical max thrust.

Comment: You use mhchem \ce{} by a weird way.

You can write `$$\ce{KMnO4(aq) + 3 H2O2(aq) -> 3 O2(g) +2 MnO2(s) +2KOH(aq) +2H2O(l)}$$` to get 

$$\ce{KMnO4(aq) + 3 H2O2(aq) -> 3 O2(g) +2 MnO2(s) +2KOH(aq) +2H2O(l)}$$

Note that phase states are recommended not to be written as subscripts.

See  https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here

Comment: BTW, it is permanganate, manganate is $\ce{K2MnO4}$. // I doubt the rate can be calculated from basic principles, so unless it is published, it must be measured. TD preference and kinetic rate are independent.

Answer (score 0):

The rate of catalyzed decomposition of H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> will depend on the state of division of the catalyst. That will certainly change over the course of the reaction as the MnO<sub>2</sub> is formed, then gets reacted upon.

H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> has been used since before World War II for propulsion of rockets and torpedoes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-test_peroxide

Although it is not stated explicitly in the Wikipedia article, it seems that the rate of decomposition of H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> is determined simply by the rate at which it is pumped into the propulsion chamber (with the catalyst separately pumped in). This assumes essentially instantaneous decomposition, which is apparently an adequate approximation.

The reaction of H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> with MnO<sub>2</sub> or KMnO<sub>4</sub> would be similar to hypergolic fuels. The first hypergolic fuel actually used H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> along with hydrazine hydrate. "Hypergolically-fueled rocket engines are usually simple and reliable because they need no ignition system. Although larger hypergolic engines in some launch vehicles use turbopumps, most hypergolic engines are pressure-fed." The reaction is said to be *spontaneous*, but more than that, it is fast, immediate, explosively fast. It is kept from exploding by limiting the amount that gets to react. You could probably call it a limited explosion; the astronauts have essentially declared that their trips are like riding an explosion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergolic_propellant